# HTML/CSS drawing a square window in a css mask

Tags: javascript, html, css, mask

So I have a grid of images (map tiles) and I draw a semi-transparent mask over it using an absolutely positioned div with width and height set to 100%.

I now want the user to be able to draw out a rectangle on the mask, with the mouse using mouse-down, drag, mouse-up. The rectangle would be drawn dynamically as the mouse moves, and the rectangle would be like a window through the mask displaying the map tiles underneath with no semi-transparency.

I'm currently looking at using 5 divs - one for the window and 4 for the mask which would be resized using javascript as I drag the mouse. Does anyone know an easier way to do this ? I'm using jquery and I need to support IE7 upwards so html5 only technology is out.

Cheers,

Colm

Comment: Your idea is how I would do it...  So good job haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [jQuery Crop plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/) does exactly what you need (Demo [here](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop)).

Maybe it's possible to carve that part out from it.

Answer (score -1):

You should try out SVG canvas instead. There's a SVG js library, good for beginner:
http://raphaeljs.com/, check it out

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH HTML5 (PLEASE DONT MIX UP WITH HTML5 CANVAS, THIS IS SVG)**

Comment: +1 for the good suggestion, but note that SVG and Canvas are not the same thing.

Comment: These are HTML5 technology and it is quite difficult to get this to work fast with IE. Quote: _"I'm using jquery and I need to support IE7 upwards so html5 only technology is out."_

Comment: I'd love to use SVG but unfortunately as mentioned by elusive, having to support IE knocks that idea out .......

Comment: seriously, try it before u knock out this suggestion, and it DOES SUPPORT IE (even IE6) cos im using it.... it has nothing to do with HTML5

Comment: IE6 does not support SVG. You are probably using a library that uses VML in IE browsers and SVG in other browsers that support it.

Comment: @Yman: There is nothing like SVG in IE. IE only has VML, which is a proprietary Microsoft thing. Like i said, it is very difficult to get this to run at acceptable speed. The same thing applies to _HTML5_ `<canvas>`, even though you removed it from your post.

Comment: what do you mean "even though you removed it from your post"?

Comment: btw, u are right, it is VML, though it still answer the question